# Java Runtime areas explanation

Tags: java, runtime, area

In JAVA, we have different types of Runtime areas.here,
I want to see each part(area) details separately and what type of code available there(in area) in JAVA Runtime areas. 
How can we check it ? please give me a suggestion to do this
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean with "Runtime areas"? Where did you get this concept from?

Comment: from internal mechanism, we have method area,java stack,heap,pc register and native method stack.Here,can we check each  area available code ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt An answer below links to old Oracle documentation for JConsole in Java 1.6, which does refers to "the method area", "the memory area", etc. The term is new to me, but it is still being used - see [Oracle's documentation for JConsole with Java 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/management/using-jconsole.htm#JSMGM-GUID-77416B38-7F15-4E35-B3D1-34BFD88350B5).

Answer (score 0):

JConsole is a monitoring tool for Java Management Extensions. It uses a wide array of JMX instrumentation and gives you data on resource consumption as well as the performance of Java applications.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html